# AR-ARCH conditional variance

Tags: time-series, variance, autoregressive, garch, conditional-expectation

Consider a AR(1)+ARCH(1) model:
\begin{align*}
&x_t=a_0+a_1x_{t-1}+u_t,\\
&u_t=\sigma_t\epsilon_t,\>\>\>\epsilon_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2_{\epsilon}),\\
&\sigma_t=\sqrt{b_0+b_1\sigma^2_{t-1}}.
\end{align*}

I want to calculate $\text{Var}(u_t|x_{t-2})$. I tried to use total law of variance
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(u_t|x_{t-2}) = \mathbb{E}(\text{Var}(u_t|x_{t-1},x_{t-2})|x_{t-2}) + \text{Var}(\mathbb{E}(u_t|x_{t-1},x_{t-2})|x_{t-2}).
\end{align*}
The first part since $u_t$ and $x_{t-1}$ are uncorrelated
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(u_t|x_{t-1},x_{t-2}) = \text{Var}(u_t|x_{t-1}) = \sigma^2_t.
\end{align*}
The second part
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(u_t|x_{t-1},x_{t-2}) = \mathbb{E}(u_t|x_{t-1}) = 0.
\end{align*}
Since $\mathbb{E}(\sigma_t^2|x_{t-2})=0$ so $\text{Var}(u_t|x_{t-2}) =0$? It doesn't seem right....

Comment: What do you think about my answer? I see you have neither upvoted nor accepted it, nor asked for further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tip: there is one point that immediately looks suspect:

> since $\mathbb{E}(\sigma_t^2|x_{t-2})=0$

The conditional expectation of a nonnegative quantity should not be zero.

Also, the variance of $\epsilon$ in an ARCH model should be 1, not $\sigma^2_{\epsilon}$.